# Connecting to PGSQL over SSL via Red Bean PHP

Tags: php, postgresql

```
$dbh = new PDO('pgsql:localhost=host;port=26257;dbname=bank;sslmode=require;sslcert=[path]/client.maxroach.crt;sslkey=[path]/client.maxroach.key;sslrootcert=[path]/ca.crt;',
    'maxroach', null, array(
      PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE          => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
      PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => true,
  ));
```

This a pdo method, i need configure red bean connection for ssl pgsql connection

```
R::setup( "pgsql:host=$ip;port=$port;dbname=$dbname",$user, $password, $frozen ); ?
```

Comment: It's unclear what your question / problem is. Please take the [tour] and read [ask] and then edit your post to include an actual question and a description of specifically what the issue is. "I need" isn't a question and doesn't describe a difficulty (it merely states a requirement).

Comment: Need more explanation. Please provide a complete use case what is the actual problem you are facing.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You definitely need to write the full path to certificates and keys,
otherwise nothing will work.

```
$crt = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/client.crt";

$key = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/client.key";

$ca = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/ca.crt";

R::setup( "pgsql:host=$ip;port=$port;dbname=$dbname;sslmode=verify-ca;sslcert=$crt;sslkey=$key;sslrootcert=$ca;",$user, $password, $frozen );
```

*sslmode=verify-ca; better use sslmode=verify-full*